# Pandas Dataframe Sort Date

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sorting, datetime

I have a csv file at http://sprunge.us/Pv338j. I created a dataframe out of it. There is a date column in it. If I try to sort on this date column, the column is not ordered. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(outputcsv)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

df.Date

0     2020-11-11
1     2020-12-11
2     2020-11-13
3     2020-11-14
4     2020-11-15
   
274   2021-12-08
275   2021-08-13
276   2021-08-14
277   2021-08-15
278   2021-08-16
Name: Date, Length: 279, dtype: datetime64[ns]

df.sort_values(by='Date', inplace=True)

df.Date
20    2020-01-12
21    2020-02-12
22    2020-03-12
23    2020-04-12
24    2020-05-12
   
152   2021-12-04
182   2021-12-05
213   2021-12-06
243   2021-12-07
274   2021-12-08
Name: Date, Length: 279, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: There is mixed format of datetimes, soemtiems swapped months with days. So problem is not in sorting, but how parsing this data to datetimes.

Comment: It looks sorted in ascending which is the default form. If you want it in descending order just use `ascending=False`

Comment: @jezrael Do I have to change them manually? I need those Dates in %Y-%m-%d format.

Comment: It is not easy converting, because sometimes `2021-02-06` means February, sometime June. Most correct is manually.

Comment: @rambalachandran I need them in ascending order. Look at the first date after sort. It's changed. First date is 2020-11-11. Same thing happened for the last date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:

```
df['Date2'] = [(d - datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds() for d in df['Date']]
                            
df['year'] = [datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(d).year for d in df['Date2']]
df['month'] = [datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(d).month for d in df['Date2']]
df['day'] = [datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(d).day for d in df['Date2']]


df.sort_values(['year', 'month', 'day'], ascending=[True, True, True])

df['Date']
```

Comment: Same output. Starts with 2020-01-12, whereas it should be 2020-11-11.

Comment: @Joydeep, try new code block, is thisyour answer?

Comment: Looks good. Thanks. Although, dates are still not ordered. I shall wait a bit if anything better comes.